# Evaluated $F=0.5+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1.8}{e^{\frac{-1}{2}x^{2}}dx} $

Tags: numerical-methods

Determine the probability of the element sell in the supermarket weight less than 5kg., using 6 intervals. We evaluated the following expression

$$F=0.5+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1.8}{e^{\frac{-1}{2}x^{2}}dx}$$

I use 6 intervals mean that $[0,1.8]=[0,0.3],[0.3,0.6],...,[1.2,1.5],[1.5,1.8]$ and I should integrate using simpson rule? Anyway, give me a Hint pls!

Comment: For the integral part, let $f(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$. Your numbers are right. We want $\frac{0.3}{3}\left(f(0)+4f(0.3)+2f(0.6)+4f(0.9)+2f(1.2)+4f(1.5)+f(1.8)\right)$. The rest is calculator work. You may want to use tables, or software, to check whether something has gone wrong in the calculation.  The ultimate number you get should be not too far from $0.964$.

Comment: There is something a little confusing about your notation. The division points are indeed $0$, $0.3$, $0.6$, and so on, but the notation is unusual, and the second interval should not be $[0,0.6]$.